# How spring projections are implemented internally

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

Can anybody explain how spring projections are implemented internally.

I have tried to cast an object to interface and that fails if the object does not implement that interface. So the only option remaining as per my knowledge is java reflections.

So does spring uses reflections to somehow bind interface methods to entity objects ?

Comment: The fullest answer at here https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beansThe central idea of Spring framwork is BeanFactory https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-beanfactory